# C# Get list of containers in a Cosmos Database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

How do I get list of container for a Cosmos Database using C#

```
var client2 = new CosmosClient("https://MYCOSMOS.documents.azure.com:443/", "kpWBLj8jfN0qDPsdfsg1Amng==");
client2.GetDatabase("").GetContainer("");
```

There is no option for **GetContainers()**

Answer (score 7):

You can archive this by this way:

```cs
private readonly CosmosClient databaseClient;

public CosmosDbManager(CosmosClient dataBaseClient)
{
    this.databaseClient = dataBaseClient;
}

public async Task GetContainer(CosmosDbConfiguration configuration)
{
    Database database = this.databaseClient.GetDatabase(configuration.Database);
    FeedIterator<ContainerProperties> iterator = database.GetContainerQueryIterator<ContainerProperties>();
    FeedResponse<ContainerProperties> containers = await iterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    foreach (var container in containers)
    {
        // do what you want with the container
    }
}
```

In your case:

```cs
CosmosClient client2 = new CosmosClient("https://MYCOSMOS.documents.azure.com:443/", "kpWBLj8jfN0qDPsdfsg1Amng==");

Database database = this.client2.GetDatabase(configuration.Database);
FeedIterator<ContainerProperties> iterator = database.GetContainerQueryIterator<ContainerProperties>();
FeedResponse<ContainerProperties> containers = await iterator.ReadNextAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

foreach (var container in containers)
{
    // for examploe container.id will return the name of your container
}
```